# How to extract data from a resource compiler script in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resource-management, file

I need to know how to extract all data from a resource compiler script to a folder or the desktop.

the .res files are compiled and added to an exe file.

.res is the file extension.

and if that is possible I need to know how to re-pack the data after it's been changed.

The shorter answer I need to extract the data from a resource compiler script aka ".res" and then after data changed re-pack the data back into the ".res" file.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a problem unique to game development. Have you tried [searching for existing answers on our general programming sister site StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=extract+resource+c%23&mixed=1)? They get much more traffic than we do, so when your question isn't about the *game* parts of a game (like how to work with game controllers or design & implement game mechanics or do realtime rendering) you'll often find answers faster there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about game development.